# android bookmark ContentProvider makes bookmark but not visible in browser's bookmarks

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, bookmarks

I'm using Android's Browser Bookmark ContentProvider to create a new bookmark programatically. The bookmark is created (I can retrieve it programatically via the ContentProvider) but the bookmark isn't visible in the browser bookmark view. Thoughts?

```
// Saving the bookmark via ContentProvider

final ContentValues bookmarkValues = new ContentValues();
bookmarkValues.put(Browser.BookmarkColumns.TITLE, title);
bookmarkValues.put(Browser.BookmarkColumns.URL, url);

final Uri newBookmark = getContentResolver().insert(Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI, bookmarkValues);

// Retrieving       
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI, 
        null, null, null, Browser.BookmarkColumns.CREATED);

cursor.moveToFirst();
final String stitle = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("title"));
final String surl = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("url"));
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add this value:

```
bookmarkValues.put(Browser.BookmarkColumns.BOOKMARK, 1);
```

Comment: Yes that's the answer, I had the same problem too and that solved it

Comment: Thanks - agreed - its that simple.

Comment: @IT-Dan : maybe you could help me on this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13725192/how-can-i-get-set-bookmarks-per-account-on-android

Comment: @Pascal sorry not sure about that one